# Spring integration no files picked

Tags: spring-integration

The following is my configuration. I was able to poll files until recently. Now the filter always gets an empty list of files. The only change i have made is install kaspersky antivirus. Hopefully that is not a problem. I can successfully access the ftp from command prompt as well as from the browser.

The conf:

```
     <int:channel id="ftpChannel"/>

 <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound1"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    local-directory="file:${paths.root}"
    delete-remote-files="false" 
    temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
    remote-directory="${file.ftpfolder}"
    preserve-timestamp="true"
     auto-startup="true" 
     filter="compositeFilterLocal"
     >
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="10000" fixed-rate="1000" error-channel="errorChannel"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutbound"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    remote-file-separator="/"
    auto-create-directory="true"
    remote-directory="DMS" 
    use-temporary-file-name="true"
     temporary-file-suffix=".writing">

  </int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>

<!-- <bean id="acceptAllFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter" /> -->
 <bean id="compositeFilterLocal" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <!-- Ensures that the file is whole before processing it -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter" />
                <bean class="com.polling.util.CustomFileFilterLocal"/>
                <!-- Ensures files are picked up only once from the directory -->

            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Please tell me if anything should be changed in it...Thanks

Please let me know if anymore information is needed!

EDIT:: Update
If I use the Apache commons-net-3.3 to retrieve the same file from the same folder, it is working fine and allowing me to take the file and download it. So this has nothing to do with jvm access to the ftp site.

EDIT::Code for the filter is simple. Currently I am only using it for pattern matching.

```
    @Override
public List<File> filterFiles(File[] files)
{
    List<File> ret = new ArrayList<File>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?~.*?");//(".*?@.*?@.*?");
    DocumentFile documentFile;
    Matcher matcher;
    for (File file : files) 
    {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(file.getName());
        if(matcher.find())// matching the input file name pattern
        {
            //get key and documentfile
            //create sha key to check file existance
            String key = EncodeUtil.generateKey(file);
            documentFile = documentDaoImpl.getDocumentFile(key,Constants.INPROGRESS);
            if (documentFile != null)
            {
                ret.add(file);
            }
        }/*else
        {
            file.delete();
        }*/
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I have been successfully working with this for atleast a couple of months and now suddenly I am getting no files!!
Currently I am in process of using a timer cron expression and will do the ftp using apache commons-net within the triggered class. Seems such a waste having to do the ftp inspite of having the spring ftp tag.

Comment: Sorry, but it is really not enough info. Any errors in log? What does your `CustomFileFilterLocal` do? Can you debug Spring Integration classes for FTP to be sure what `FtpSession` returns for the `LS` command - `AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer` ?

Comment: No errors in the log just the message 0 files transferred. Can I check the directory it is polling within the filter?

Answer (score 1):

I have built a project with the configuration you have used and everything seems to work fine.

There are some pieces in your code (not posted here) that might lead to discard the files in the filter and that you will have to check (adding log messages will help):

```
if (matcher.find())// matching the input file name pattern
{
    // get key and documentfile
    // create sha key to check file existance

    // TODO: does this call throw any exception? return null?
    String key = EncodeUtil.generateKey(file);
    documentFile = documentDaoImpl.getDocumentFile(key, Constants.INPROGRESS);
    if (documentFile != null) {
        ret.add(file);
    }
    else {
        // TODO: Log here that your DAO implementation did not return anything for this specific file
    }
}
  else { 
      // TODO: Log here that the file does not meet the naming convention
}
```